# Updating the current_value of a sequence in SQL Server when the current_value is out of sync with the table row that uses it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've had a few rare instances where the generated row id of a table becomes out-of-sync with the sequence in my SQL Server 2012 database.

So I tried executing this query:

```
update sys.sequences 
set current_value = (select max(id) from game.gfxMedia)
where object_id = 1661237544
```

And not surprisingly I got this error:

> Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

What is the "proper" way of updating the `current_value` of a sequence in rare cases such as mine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
ALTER SEQUENCE <seq_name> Restart with <new_number>
```

Comment: Can I use the <object_id> instead of <seq_name>, the way our DB is set up, the <seq_name> values are not unique.  Thanks!

Comment: no, you cannot use object_id to replace <seq_name>. On the other hand, the <seq_name> is unique inside a database because a sequence is a user-defined schema bound object. In another word, you cannot create two seq with the same name inside a SAME db. If your really want to use object_id, you can use select name from sys.objects where object_id=<object_id> to find the seq name and compose a dynamic sql to alter the sequence.